# Keep data AppWidgetProvider when rotation

Tags: java, android, service, rotation, widget

I've since a few days a problem with my AppWidgetProvider when the screen is rotating I loose all information inside like information from database. I've tried to use a service in background to receive these information after the screen rotation but it's doesn't work.

Here I start the service :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class));
    Log.i("V7", "V7 getAction " + intent.getAction());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_LAUNCH_APPLICATION)) {
        Log.i("V7", "V7 Launch");
        launchMainActivity(context);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UPDATE_ACTION_SIGN_IN)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String hour = extras.getString("hour");
        String action = extras.getString("action");
        String accountsName = "";
        Integer accountId = null;
        try {
            accountId = extras.getInt("account");
            if (accountId != null) {
                accountsName = (connection.readJSON("name", String.valueOf(accountId), null, "account.analytic.account")).getString("name");
            }

            Intent intentService = new Intent(context, MyUpdateService.class);
            intentService.putExtra("hour", hour);
            intentService.putExtra("action", action);
            intentService.putExtra("account", accountsName);
            context.startService(intentService);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            accountsName = "";
        }
```

This is my service class :

```
public static class MyUpdateService extends Service {
        Intent intent;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            this.intent = intent;

            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            // Update the widget
            RemoteViews remoteView = buildRemoteView(this);

            // Push update to homescreen
            pushUpdate(remoteView);

            // No more updates so stop the service and free resources
            stopSelf();
        }

        public RemoteViews buildRemoteView(Context context) {

            int layoutID = R.layout.mainwidget2;

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);

            // Code to build and update the remote view
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvHour, context.getString(R.string.tvHour) + " " + intent.getStringExtra("hour"));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvLastAction, context.getString(R.string.tvLastAction) + " " + intent.getStringExtra("action"));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAccount, intent.getStringExtra("account"));

            return views;
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            RemoteViews remoteView = buildRemoteView(this);
            // Push update to home screen
            pushUpdate(remoteView);
        }

        private void pushUpdate(RemoteViews remoteView) {
            ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(this, WidgetProvider.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteView);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my Manifest :

```
  <service android:name="android.timesheets.MyUpdateService" />
```

My service seems never launch...

If you have another way to keep my information I'm aware.

I hope that you could help me.